# CSS3 - divs one on each other, borders, triangles

Tags: css, border, gradient

I'm in trouble trying to do this :

[image: see this]

I managed to do something like this :

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;

background: rgb(245,245,245); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245,245,245,1) 0%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(245,245,245,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(230,230,230,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245,245,245,1) 0%,rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245,245,245,1) 0%,rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245,245,245,1) 0%,rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245,245,245,1) 0%,rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e6e6e6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

for the main container of text, and :

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 25px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
border-left: 40px solid #FEEDDD;
display: inline-block;
```

to do the triangle. I would then place the circle with the number in absolute position inside of it.

But can't figure out how I would do for the triangle "border" to be gradient like the other div, nor giving it a white outer border...

Thanks ahead !

Comment: try this link, http://www.css3shapes.com/ you might have to use some :before and :after pseudo classes to accomplish what you want

Comment: Very nice website, thank you, but from what I can see it uses the same techniques I saw elsewhere sooo I guess it will be hard to achieve what I'm trying to do (or simply i'm not skilled enough to manage it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible.

I created not so long ago a back button with a gradient arrow. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRALm/1/)
So just change the orientation, the colors and resize it to what you want but you've got the idea here I guess.

HTML:

```
<button>Rejoignez le groupe</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #eeeeee), color-stop(100%, #888888));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #888888);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #888888);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #888888);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #888888);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0 1px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0 1px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0 1px 0;
}

button:after {
  clip: rect(14px, 14px, 28px, 1px);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-35deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-35deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-35deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(-35deg);
  transform: skewX(-35deg);
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 8%;
  right: -10px;
  border-right: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inherit;
  -moz-box-shadow: inherit;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

button:before{
  clip: rect(1px, 14px, 14px, 1px);
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(35deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(35deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(35deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(35deg);
  transform: skewX(35deg);
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 8%;
  right: -10px;
  border-right: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inherit;
  -moz-box-shadow: inherit;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}
```

---

Tell me if it's too confusing and need some guidance to change orientation, size and colors.

Comment: I updated the css, html and fiddle so they have the right orientation and the text is the one you have in your screenshot

Comment: I worked on it on my side (I love to understand things :) ) and managed to come to this : http://jsfiddle.net/DRNpT/ That's great ! I will set the white circle absolute so it displays where it needs to. What I don't get, is how you could use this to get the result I need : the first div is done, but how can you set it "in" his neighbor, so his gray color appears up and down the triangle ?

Comment: It looks good, well done! To handle the neighbor problem, the easiest way that would require small css change is to play around with the margin left for the neighbors, the divs will go on top of each others. The z-index will do to set them in the right order.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DRNpT/1/

Answer (score 0):

while you probably can manage to do something like that and still maintain a decent fall-backs across the ranges of browsers with successful results... i expect your going to pull out a good chunk of your hair while trying.  my suggestion would be to get a few background images made up in Photoshop and break those items up into three different elements

1. an element for the transparent white circle that can contain the
   step #
2. an element with class for the completed steps to apply the orange gradient background
3. another element with separate class for the gray gradient

doing things this way you can keep all of your elements "square" without having to worry about support for triangular or circle elements. and just overlay your text in the appropriate places...

i know this might not be exactly what your asking for the css3 way to accomplish everything, but i believe doing things this way allows you to keep it simple & lean